# Breeze sample does not work in IE

Tags: breeze

I create a MVC 4 application (WebAPI or empty) and I load the Breeze NuGet packages and hit F5 like they say I should, if I run in Google Chrome or Page Inspector all goes well, if I run in the current IE 10 I get an exception on the last line:

```
(function (root) {
    var ko = root.ko,
        breeze = root.breeze,
        logger = root.app.logger;

// service name is route to the Web API controller
var serviceName = 'api/BreezeSample';

// manager is the service gateway and cache holder
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

Essentially root.breeze is undefined, any idea why this is happening? How would the browser influence that?
How would I fix it? (I'm using VS 2012 Express for Web with all the updates loaded)

Comment: Would like to help. Please look at the network traffic to see if breeze.debug.js is among the scripts sent down from the server.

Comment: @Ward Thanks for trying to help me, that is being sent down from the server yes but with status code 304, is that the issue?

Comment: Ok, if I clear my history I get the file with a code 200 but I still get the error

Answer (score 1):

Adriaan,

I tried to replicate your error but could not. Here are the steps I used to get it up and running in IE10 (also using VS Express 2012 for Web):

1. **File**
2. **New Project...**
3. **ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application (Visual C#)**
4. **Empty**
5. **Tools**
6. **Library Package Manager**
7. **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**
8. Search for **Breeze**.
9. Install **Breeze for ASP.NET MVC4 Web Api Sample**.
10. **Ok**
11. **I Accept**
12. **Close**
13. **F5**

Everything worked as expected.

I know it isn't the same error you are having, but if it makes you feel better, I failed out the first time I tried this as I selected **ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application (Visual Basic)** instead of the **C#** version. Sure to fail and embarrassing once I realized the mistake.

Comment: I would like to accept this as the answer because it works on my one machine, but not the other...